# Opening multiple password protected workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to open multiple password protected excel workbooks. I have a master wb that has macros. It has a worksheet labeled "Dashboard". In this worksheet, the file directory for all the files is listed at the top. There are two columns below the directory. The left column lists the file name and a column next to it that lists the password for each file. I am trying to create a loop that will open all the files. I need this to refresh the data contained within. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Tried a number of Do while loop arrangements but all create errors.

```
Dim mainwb As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim pw As String
Dim myExtension As String

Set mainwb = ThisWorkbook

myPath = ActiveSheet.Range("C1")
myExtension = ".xlsx"
myFile = ActiveCell
pw = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A4").Select

Do While myFile <> ""

     Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile & myExtension, Password:=pw)

     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to try looping through the cells that contain the file names and passwords, that way you open a file with the path from cell `C1`, with the name from cell `A2` and the password from cell `B2`, close it (which you macro doesn't do right now) and then move on to the next file listed in `A3`

Comment: The issue with that is I need to open them all then do a refresh all of the power query query the close them all. To refresh they all need to be opened.

Comment: Ah! I did not realize that. Then ignore my suggestion of closing them. The rest still applies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will open all the files listed in the "Dashboard" sheet (I assumed you had 5 files, change the loop to match your file):

```
myPath = mainwb.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C1")
myExtension = ".xlsx"

For i = 4 to 8
    myFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A" & i).Value
    pw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B" & i).Value
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & myFile & myExtension, Password:=pw
next i
```

You may also want to reset screen updating, events and calculation before ending your sub:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The following line is showing a syntax error.```Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile & myExtension, Password:=pw)````

Comment: If that answer works for you, consider marking it as correct by clicking on the check-mark you see on the left of it

Comment: The workbooks.Open line is showing a syntax error. When I rewrite it it gives a compile error expecting a =. Any reason why that would be?

Comment: Just needed to remove the brackets. Ty so much!